# Django - JSON Serialization error

Tags: python, json, django, django-models, django-queryset

I would like to know why this data retrieved from queryset cannot be serialized in JSON ?

```
objectList = Layers.objects.all()

data = [objectList.values('id', 'name', 'geom_type')]

jsonData = json.dumps(data)

>>> [{'id': 7, 'geom_type': u'Polygon', 'name': u'ra_general'}, {'id': 6, 'geom_type': u'Polygon', 'name': u'square'}] is not JSON serializable
```

what is the proper way to achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`values()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.values) returns a `ValuesQuerySet` which is not directly serializable via `json.dumps()`.

Convert it to `list` before dumping:

```
values = objectList.values('id', 'name', 'geom_type')
data = list(values)  # becomes list of dictionaries
jsonData = json.dumps(data)
```